# Regular expression missed first occurrence of target string

Tags: php, html, regex

I am using regular expression to fetch both text1 and text2 in the following html code. Here is what I am using:
`/<div\s?class="right-col">[\s\n\S]*<a[\s\n]?[^>]*>@(.*)<\/a>/`
but apparently I missed text1, only got text2(here is the [link to my problem](http://rubular.com/r/y9lrWrZasy)).

```
<div class="right-col">
    <h1>
        <a href="url-link-here" title="title-here">title1</a>
    </h1>
    <p>some text here</p>
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="left">
        <span><a href="url-link-here" class="breaking" target="_blank">some text here </a></span>      
    </div>
    <div class="postmeta"><a href="url-link-here" >@text1</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="right-col">
    <h1>
        <a href="url-link-here" title="title-here">title2</a>
    </h1>
    <p>some text here</p>
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="left">
        <span><a href="url-link-here" class="breaking" target="_blank">some text here </a></span>      
    </div>
    <div class="postmeta"><a href="url-link-here" >@text2</a> </div>
</div>
```

Can you guys tell me what went wrong in my regular expression? Is there a better way to capture both title1, title2 and text1, text2?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use HTML parsing methods?

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression here?  This is HTML.  You *don't* parse/match HTML with a regex.  You *should* use a DOM/XML parser.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I am using PHP to read through the html page to get certain strings I need.

Comment: So use PHP's `DOMDocument` class.  It will make this much easier.

Comment: try `<div\s?class="right-col">[\s\n\S]*?<a[\s\n]?[^>]*>@(.*)<\/a>`, just added `?` to make the match eager

Comment: @Fabricator Thank you so much! This is the first time I learned that "*" and "?" can be combined. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly common issue with regular expressions as they are greedy. [\s\S]* (the \n is not needed) matches for the first '<' and 'a' and since it's greedy it will match those and continue. Adding a ? makes it not greedy and using your link returns both text1 and text2.

The short answer is to replace [\s\n\S]* with [\s\S]*? but as others have mentioned, this is probably not a good use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression here is not the best way to do it.  It's bad practice.  You should be using a DOM/XML parser to do this.

I like using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) class.  Using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), we can quickly find the elements you want

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$aTags = $xPath->query('//div[@class="some-class"]//a[starts-with(text(), "@")]');

foreach($aTags as $a){
    echo $a->nodeValue;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QHOXzH

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much for providing the detailed solution.

Comment: You're welcome.  Once I learned how to use XPath, it was so much easier to use than regexes with HTML.